# Adding unique row into gridview after every x rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

### Intro

I'm trying to add a custom row on every 25th row. (25, 50, 75...) The custom row should be like

- (start sale button)(create customer
  button)(textbox)(textbox)(textbox)(textbox)(textbox)

Essentially mimicking the example gridview's format below. The reason for this is to quickly add a customer and do something with them. Moving forward once the information is inside the textboxes won't be an issue.

Using:

1. ASP.net
2. C#

### The Problem

I've come across a lot of different examples for doing this, but none where I add a row that's different from the item templates that are already there. In this case having a textbox on the 25th row instead of a label. I'm not sure if this is possible or where to begin with this.

### Declaration of the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCustomersSearched" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="grdCustomersSearched_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25" OnPageIndexChanging="grdCustomersSearched_PageIndexChanging" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sale">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnStartSale" CommandName="StartSale" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerId") %>' Text="Start Sale" runat="server">Start Sale</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Profile">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnViewCustomer" CommandName="ViewProfile" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerId") %>' Text="View Profile" runat="server">View Profile</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Number">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CustomerId") %>' ID="key"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("firstName") + " " + Eval("lastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Address">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("primaryAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone Number">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("primaryPhoneNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("city") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No current customer data, please search for a customer
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

### Codebehind for populating gridview

The following code gathers the data that is needed and populates the gridview.

```
protected void btnCustomerSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //Looks through database and returns a list of customers
        //based on the search criteria entered
        SweetShopManager ssm = new SweetShopManager();
        c = ssm.GetCustomerfromSearch(txtSearch.Text);
        //Binds the results to the gridview
        grdCustomersSearched.Visible = true;
        grdCustomersSearched.DataSource = c;
        grdCustomersSearched.DataBind();            
    }
```

### Example of the gridview

[image: Example of the gridview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the `RowCreated` event of a GridView. This works best with `AutoGenerateColumns` set to false.

```
int rowIndex = 0;

protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //the amount of rows in between the inserted rows
    int rowsInBetween = 3;

    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && rowIndex % (rowsInBetween + 1) == 0 && rowIndex > 0)
    {
        //create a new row
        GridViewRow extraRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        extraRow.BackColor = Color.Green;

        //add one cell with text
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Text = "ExtraRow";
        extraRow.Cells.Add(cell1);

        //add another one with a textbox and column spanning
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        cell2.ColumnSpan = GridView1.Columns.Count - 1;
        TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
        tb1.Text = "Inserted TextBox";
        cell2.Controls.Add(tb1);
        extraRow.Cells.Add(cell2);

        //add the new row to the gridview
        GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(rowIndex, extraRow);

        //extra increment the row count
        rowIndex++;
    }

    rowIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is almost exactly what I was looking for. I do have another question though. Since I am using paging on the gridview and limiting it to 25 pieces of data, if I set rowsInBetween to 24, it is there, but I have one line of data after it. If I set it to 25, it is no longer there. Is it possible to have it show as the last line instead of data, or is it an issue with the paging?

Comment: Then why not use a `FooterTemplate`? Then you don't even need to add rows programatically.